# How to make the list view scroll as my list item expand/collapse

Tags: android

I have a list view in android. And in each list item, user can expand/collapse when click on that list item. My question is how can I make the list view scroll to make the whole list item visible to user as I click the last item item which causes the last list item to expand and hence the list item increase its size (height)?

And same thing goes for when I click the list item to make the list item collapse (which makes it reduces its size)?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use:

```
listView1.smoothScrollToPosition(int position);
```

Or

```
listView1.smoothScrollByOffset(int offset);
```

Comment: I have tried 'smoothScrollToPosition(int position)'. It works for the last element (i.e. the list view does scroll to make the whole list item to be visible). But it does not work for the second last list element. The list does not scroll.

Comment: Try calling  `listView1.setSelection(position)` to get the listview to scroll to the item.